# Does an operators (such as +) behave more like a curried function or a function with an argument of a pair tuple type?

Tags: haskell, language-lawyer

[How can I find out the type of operator "+"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57028635/how-can-i-find-out-the-type-of-operator#comment100586985_57028665) says operator `+` isn't a function.

Which does an operator such as `+` **behave** more like,

- a curried function, or
- a function whose argument has a pair tuple type?

By an operator say `#`, I mean `#` not `(#)`. `(#)` is a curried function, and if `#` behaves like a curried function, I guess there is no need to have `(#)`, isn't it?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use the `(+)` function, `(+)` is just a curried function, since `(+) 2` is a function that will add `2` to that number, and `(+) 2 5` is thus `7`.

Comment: An operator is not a function so it does not behave like any of the two. It is just notation. `x + y` is short for `(+) x y`.

Comment: I am asking which one it is more like

Comment: well since it isn't any of the two "at all", it is hard to answer that. An operator is just a syntactical construct (*syntactical sugar). In reality if you write `x + y`, you wrote `(+) x y`. So in the "Haskell world", it does not even exist. It is just some sort of "front-end" to make things more convenient, just like in mathematics.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem That is why I am asking abut "behave" not "appearance". Do you mean  GHC immediately and equivalently translate `x + y` into `(+) x y`. So it behaves just the same as a curried function?

Comment: It doesn't just *behave* like a curried function; `x + y` is just *syntax* for the application of an *acutal*  (curried) function.

Comment: Well `x ?? y` can sometimes behave as a curried function yes, for example `(x >=> y)` is a function that takes a value. For `x + y`, given your `Num` instance is a function `x + y` behaves as a function as well.

Comment: I'm surprised at some of the statements above. I have always believed that operators in Haskell in fact *are* functions, and that this is one of the nice features of the language, that it doesn't have an arbitrary distinction between the two as most other languages do. The only thing that distinguishes them in Haskell is that an "operator" is used in infix position by default, and that a function whose name contains no alphanumeric characters is treated as an operator. That is the only difference.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem does operator `+` require two arguments be presented at the same time, or can it take just one argument like a curried function does?

Comment: @RobinZigmond You are entirely correct. It's just that when people say "operator" they often mean to emphasise the syntactical peculiarities -- precisely the ones we don't care about when we note how nice it is that operators are ultimately functions like any other.

Comment: @Tim yes of course `+` can be partially applied. For example `(+) 2`, or `(2+)` (or `(+2)`, they're equivalent since `+` is commutative) as it would usually be written (those last two forms are both "sections", which are shorthand and more intuitive ways to write partially applied operators) is the function which takes a number and returns the number that's 2 more. Try playing about with some examples in GHCi, I'm sure you'll soon get used to it, eg `addOne = (1+)`, then look at `:t addOne`, `addOne 5`, `addOne 1.5` etc

Answer (score 6):

According to the Haskell 2010 report:

> An operator symbol [not starting with a colon] is an ordinary identifier.<sup>1</sup>

Hence, `+` is an identifier. Identifiers can identify different things, and in the case of `+`, it identifies a function from the `Num` typeclass. That function behaves like any other Haskell function, except for different parsing rules of expressions involving said functions.

Specifically, this is described in **3.2**.

> An operator is a function that can be applied using
>   infix syntax (Section 3.4), or partially applied using a section (Section 3.5).

In order to determine what constitutes an operator, we can read further:

> An operator is either an operator symbol, such as `+` or `$$`, or is an ordinary identifier enclosed in grave accents (backquotes), such as `` `op` ``<sup>2</sup>.

---

So, to sum up:

`+` is an *identifier*. It's an *operator symbol*, because it doesn't start with a colon and only uses non-alphanumeric characters. When used in an expression (parsed as a part of an expression), we treat it as an *operator*, which in turn means it's a function.

To answer your question specifically, everything you said involves just syntax. The need for `()` in expressions is merely to enable prefix application. In all other cases where such disambiguation isn't necessary (such as `:type`), it might have simply been easier to implement that way, because you can then just expect ordinary identifiers and push the burden to provide one to the user.

---

<sup>1</sup> For what it's worth, I think the report is actually misleading here. This specific statement seems to be in conflict with other parts, crucially this:

> Dually, an operator symbol can be converted to an ordinary identifier by enclosing it in parentheses.

My understanding it is that in the first quote, the context for "ordinary" means that it's not a type constructor operator, but a value category operator, hence "value category" means "ordinary". In other quotes, "ordinary" is used for identifiers which are not operator-identifiers; the difference being obviously the application. That would corroborate the fact that enclosing an operator identifier in parens, we turn it into an ordinary identifier *for the purposes of prefix application*. Phew, at least I didn't write that report ;)

<sup>2</sup> I'd like to point out one additional thing here. Neither `` `(+)` `` nor `` (`add`) `` do actually parse. The second one is understandable, since the report specifically says that enclosing in parens only works for operator *identifiers*, one can see that `` `add` ``, while being an operator, isn't an operator identifier like `+`.

The first case is actually a bit more tricky for me. Since we can obtain an operator by enclosing an ordinary identifier in backticks, `(+)` isn't exactly "as ordinary" as `add`. The language, or at least GHC parser that I tested this with, seems to differentiate between "ordinary ordinary" identifiers, and ordinary identifiers obtained by enclosing operator symbols with parens. Whether this actually contradicts the spec or is another case of mixed naming is beyond my knowledge at this point.

Comment: Heck, it doesn't happen often for me that the footnotes get longer than an actual answer. If someone more experienced with the Haskell specifications could shed some light on those doubts, that would be great.

Comment: I think it's more accurate to say that the parentheses *disable* infix interpretation, rather than enabling prefix application (which is just a consequence of the regular parsing algorithm). For example, `(+) = 3` is a legal definition, which requires `show (+)` instead of `show +` to parse correctly. (For that matter, the parentheses also disable infix interpretation in the definition, since `+ = 3` would not parse. )

Comment: On footnote 1, that's basically it, though note that the Report is talking about value constructors there (type operators require a language extension to be enabled). On footnote 2, cf. [*Why does “(\`subtract\`) 1 2” fail?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25173277/2751851)

Comment: does operator + require two arguments be presented at the same time, or can it take just one argument like a curried function does?

Comment: `\`(+)\`` doesn't work because `(+)` is not an identifier! It's for the same reason that `\`(add)\`` doesn't work; backticks are a syntactic option that you can only apply to something that is literally an identifier, not an expression containing an identifier. "An operator symbol can be converted to an ordinary identifier by enclosing it in parentheses" is imprecise language, certainly, since they're using "converted to an ordinary identifier" to mean "converted so that you can apply it prefix like you would a non-operator identifier". The identifier is **just** the name.

Comment: maybe we could say, `+` is an operator symbol *syntactically* which means it denotes a function *semantically*. To refer to the `+` *function*, syntax rules dictate that we must enclose the `+` symbol in parentheses, like so: `(+)`. so yea, it *is* just syntax, furthermore `GHCi> :i +` *works* -- without the parentheses. `:t` expects a typeable entity, but `:i` expects an identifier (or something).

Answer (score 6):

`(+)` and `+` refer to the same thing, a function of type `Num a => a -> a -> a`. We spell it as `(+)` when we want to use it prefix, and `+` when we want to write it infix. There is no essential difference; [it is just a matter of syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56960590/2751851).

> So `+` (without section) behaves just like a function which requires a pair argument [because a section is needed for partial application]. `()` works like currying.

While this is not unreasonable from a syntactical point of view, I wouldn't describe it like that. Uncurried functions in Haskell take a tuple as an argument (say, `(a, a) -> a` as opposed to `a -> a -> a`), and there isn't an actual tuple anywhere here. `2 + 3` is better thought of as an abbreviation for `(+) 2 3`, the key point being that the function being used is the same in both cases.

Comment: does operator + require two arguments be presented at the same time, or can it take just one argument like a curried function does?

Comment: @Tim To supply just one argument while spelling it as `+`, you have to use a section. For instance, `(3 +)` is the same as `(+) 3`. The function being used is the same in both cases; the difference is merely syntactical.

Comment: So `+` (without section) behaves just like a function which requires a pair argument. `()` works like currying.

Comment: @Tim Now I see what you're trying to get at. Though it kind of makes sense if you look at it in a certain way, I wouldn't describe it like that, as in `2 + 3` there isn't an actual pair involved anywhere. `2 + 3` is better thought of as an abbreviation for `(+) 2 3`.

Comment: @Tim For me, a pair argument is `(a,b)`, and a function taking a pair is `(a,b) -> c`. Regardless of whether you apply it as infix or prefix, the type of `+` is `a -> a -> b`, so it's curried.